# How to get file in glassfish project folder

Tags: java, glassfish-3, java-io

I want get file and zip it. When GlassFish in my PC OS: Windows, Path:

> D:\NetbeansWorkspace\MyProjectV2\root

work normally. But use Linux server GlassFish error

> HTTP Status 500 java.io.FileNotFoundException:

I know Linux path type different with Windows. How can I use project folder? Any suggest?

Answer (score 0):

You should use relative path instead of the absolute path.The file or directory should exist inside the Project contents .Do not use `"/"` in the beginning as it would mean absolute path .Simply use the path as `"images/macro/abc.png"`